# CSS Not closing

Tags: css

I have no idea why not but this CSS is not closing and basically just making everything under it part of the same CSS

```
#colTwoPromotion {
float:right; 
-mox-box-shadow:    -10px 10px 12px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: -10px 10px 28px 2px #000;
box-shadow:         -10px 10px 28px 6px #000;
width: 365px;
border: 9px solid white;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(3deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(3deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(3deg);
transform:         rotate(3deg);
margin-bottom:40px;
min-height:400px;
/* fallback */
background-color: #E7E7E7;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
/* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#E7E7E7), to(#FFF));
 /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
/* Firefox 3.6+ */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
 /* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7;
/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
color:#000;
}
```

This is the site its currently on css line 470

[Testing Site](http://www.plusonetesting.co.uk/whiteHorse36116/whats-on.php)
Thank in advance

G

Answer (score 5):

You've missed a closing bracket on the IE 10 background line. Try this:

```css
#colTwoPromotion {
    float: right; 
       -mox-box-shadow: -10px 10px 12px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 10px 28px 2px #000;
            box-shadow: -10px 10px 28px 6px #000;
    width: 365px;
    border: 9px solid white;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
            transform: rotate(3deg);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#E7E7E7), to(#FFF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Actually it's a closing parenthesis ;)

Comment: Technically, yes. But in modern parlance, "bracket" has become synonymous with "parenthesis".

Comment: There is always the saying that goes like : "If you understood what I said, then I said it correctly". +1 Anyways

Answer (score 1):

Please correct :

```css
 /* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7;
```

To :

```css
 /* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```css
 /* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7;
```

You have to change into this:

```css
 /* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7);
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is IE10
u dont close pranthesis,when u close its,the code syntax is true

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #E7E7E7;
```